# Concatenate a number and "%" in sass

Tags: css, sass

I would like to do the following using SASS:

```
width: #{$percent}%;
```

Where `$percent` is a variable containing a number.  If `$percent` is equal to 50, the precompiled CSS would be:

```
width: 50%;
```

What syntax should I use?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Multiply by 1%:

```
$percent: 50

.foo
  width: $percent * 1%
```

Result:

```
.foo {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking answer for SCSS below code will work perfectly, just use css calc.

```
$percent: 50

.foo{
   width: calc(#{$percent} * 1%)
 }
```